# Add attachment button to a custom new form SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, newform

I'm creating a new custom form using SharePoint Designer 2013.

I would like to add a attachment button to be able to upload files and images.
How can this be done?

This is what im adding to my new custom new form:

```
   <tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>Attach Files</nobr>
</h3>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="attachmentsOnClient" style="width: 434px">
<span dir="ltr">
<input type="file" name="fileupload0" id="onetidIOFile" size="56" title="Name"></input>
</span>
</td>
<td width="100px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="Attach" onclick='OkAttach()' style="width: 6em;
height: 1.7em" id="attachOKbutton" />
<span id="idSpace"></span>
</td>
</tr>

                    <tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
                        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
                            <SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
                            <script>
          var elm = document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsTable&quot;);
          if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
          document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsRow&quot;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;;
        </script>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

[image: See error of screen shot Im now getting]

Comment: Has anyone tried with multiple attachments because with this code I am able to save only one Item in the list although you can attach multiple items in the new form but when you save the item only one item will be saved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom list form or go to your NewForm.aspx  using SharePoint Designer. Place the below code where you would like to insert the Attachment Field

```
<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>Attach Files</nobr>
</h3>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="attachmentsOnClient" style="width: 434px">
<span dir="ltr">
<input type="file" name="fileupload0"  id="onetidIOFile" size="56" title="Name">              </input>
</span>
</td>
<td width="100px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="Attach" onclick='OkAttach()'       style="width: 6em;
 height: 1.7em" />
<span id="idSpace"></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

[Reference](http://prashobjp.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/sharepoint-attachment-field-in-list-forms/)

Comment: Jinxed this doesn't work. Have you used this code before and did it work?.Also change okAttach to UploadAttachment but now getting error: The form was customized and attachments will not work correctly
because the HTML span element doesnnot contain an id attribute span

Comment: The same worked for me.

Comment: I am not able to recreate your issue. And you don't have to change anything in the code. Use it as it is and it will work. Where have you placed this code?

Comment: Jinxed how did you create the custom form?

Comment: using sharepoint designer. You can see the steps here-https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-list-form-using-SharePoint-Designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105

Comment: I have edited my original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18471/discussion-between-naijacoder-and-jinxed).

Comment: Thanks Jinxed where am i suppose to place the code?

Comment: I have mentioned it in the chat.

Comment: Thanks.Thats exactly what I was doing. I reckon i am doing something wrong here.If I can ask how did you create the custom form?

Comment: Thanks Jinxed got it I was creating the cutom list by creating a dataview webpart first :(

Comment: Also if you want to make the item required, you need to add the following after the name  <span class="ms-formvalidation"> * </span>

Answer (score 0):

- Open the form, NewForm.aspx page of respective list in advance mode in SharePoint Designer 2013
- Find the section

**`<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server>`"**

- Insert the below section

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {

var newRowContent ="<tr>"+
                    "<td width=\"190px\" valign=\"top\" class=\"ms-formlabel\">"+
                        "<h3 class=\"ms-standardheader\">"+
                            "<nobr>Attach Files</nobr>"+
                        "</h3>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td valign=\"top\" class=\"ms-formbody\" id=\"attachmentsOnClient\" style=\"width: 434px\">"+
                        "<span dir=\"ltr\">"+
                            "<input type=\"file\" name=\"fileupload0\"  id=\"onetidIOFile\" size=\"39%\" title=\"Name\"></input>"+
                        "</span>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td width=\"100px\" valign=\"top\" class=\"ms-formbody\">"+
                        "<input name=\"Button1\" type=\"button\" value=\"Attach\" onclick='OkAttach()' style=\"width: 6em; height: 3em\" />"+
                        "<span id=\"idSpace\"></span>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "</tr>";
var hiddenAttachDispId=document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow");
$(hiddenAttachDispId).before(newRowContent);
});
</script>
```

- **Save it** and try to add new item to the custom list or refresh **(Ctl+F5)** the already opened NewForm.aspx page in browser!