# Attachement button in the column field

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, sharepoint-designer, newform, button

i used the below attachment button code, which works good:

[Add attachment button to a custom new form SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120226/add-attachment-button-to-a-custom-new-form-sharepoint-2013)

Only issue is that, i want attachment to be link to the column, for example i create a new column name "AttachHereFile" and when i will upload the file it to be linked in "AttachHereFile" column. because i have a 2 list and i want to send "AttachHereFile" column from one list to another.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, it's not possible. Attachments can only be stored in the column as files, not as links.